# Coldbox sample ColdboxFlexTester issue

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, railo, coldbox

I am a newbie with Coldbox and Railo and I am trying to get the ColdboxFlexTester sample to work. The problem is that my directory is set up like this:

- Application(ColdboxFlexTester)

  - /bin

    - ColdboxFlexTester.html
  - /webroot

    - Application.cfc
    - index.cfm

And I would like to access the ColdboxFlexTester.html that is inside the bin directory through the browser like so www.mysite.com/ColdboxFlexTester/bin/ColdboxFlexTester.html, but because it is outside of the webroot, I am getting a 404 error. How would I fix this? Is there some kind of permissions I need to enable somewhere? and if so, how would I do that? Any help on this would be truly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tonih

Comment: What is the purpose of an HTML file that is not web accessible?  Can't  you just move it under your webroot? You can create virtual directories using your web server to access files outside of the webroot but then you are granting access to those directories from the internet!  What about security?

Comment: It is the way coldbox created the sample. I am just trying to get it to work - https://github.com/ColdBox/coldbox-samples/tree/master/applications/ColdboxFlexTester.

Also, I did try adding it under the webroot, but i still get a 404 error. I am thinking perhaps some type of permissions is required. Are you able to get the sample working as is? Thanks for your response.

Comment: "You can create virtual directories using your web server to access files outside of the webroot but then you are granting access to those directories from the internet"

How do I do this? I would just like to get the app running as is, then from there I can customize it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about ColdBox. However, looking at the [readme.txt file here](https://github.com/ColdBox/coldbox-samples) the directory structure mentioned for the samples does not match what you have. That doc shows that everything is installed under the webroot and for the samples you browse to `http://{your web address}/coldbox/samples`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your assistance. I simply trashed railo and just used the built in cf dev server and all works now.